# "RuntimeException: Problems with NPM resolution" when running Play application in Windows 7

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

On typing the command `sbt clean compile` and `sbt clean run` within the directory of my Play Framework application gives me the following error. The project runs fine in an Ubuntu environment. However it doesn't seem to run when in a Windows 7 environment. I have tried searches online without getting any much help. I tried the solution at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less/issues/68 , where I deleted project/target & project/project but that doesn't fix it. Please help

Unexpected exception

> RuntimeException: Problems with NPM resolution. Aborting build. No
>   source available

here is the exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems with NPM resolution. Aborting build.
     scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
     com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsEngine$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(SbtJsEngine.scala:114)
     com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsEngine$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(SbtJsEngine.scala:91)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$1.apply(Tracked.scala:253)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$1.apply(Tracked.scala:253)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Tracked.scala:267)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Tracked.scala:263)
     sbt.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:224)
     sbt.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:206)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Tracked.scala:263)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Tracked.scala:262)
     sbt.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:224)
     sbt.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:200)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$2.apply(Tracked.scala:262)
     sbt.FileFunction$$anonfun$cached$2.apply(Tracked.scala:260)
     com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsEngine$$anonfun$2.apply(SbtJsEngine.scala:122)
     com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsEngine$$anonfun$2.apply(SbtJsEngine.scala:86)
     scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
     sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
     sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
     sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
     sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
     sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
     sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsEngine npmNodeModules step creates the issue. [Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/TJdFx1eXQZA) provided the following solution to disabled this step during build:
Setting `JsEngineKeys` to `Nil` in `build.sbt` as shown below solved the issue:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(
    // Disable NPM node modules
    JsEngineKeys.npmNodeModules in Assets := Nil,
    JsEngineKeys.npmNodeModules in TestAssets := Nil
  )
```